# Typescript Typehint Observable or NotObservable

Tags: typescript, type-hinting

I'm trying to write a function with correct typehints. It works with explicit type hinting but with automatic type hinting it breaks. Where is my error and how would I write the function correct that the test 4 compiles as intended?

```js
type NotObservable<T> = T extends (Observable<unknown>|Observable<unknown>[]) ? never : T;
function piped<Ob>(fn: (value: string) => (Observable<Ob>|NotObservable<Ob>)): Observable<Ob>{…}


// Test 1: number
const valueF = (test: string): number => 42;
piped(valueF).pipe(map(x => x));
// works - x is typeof number


// Test 2: Observable<string>
const observable = (test: string): Observable<string> => of(test);
piped(observable).pipe(map(x => x));
// works - x is typeof string


// Test 3: Observable<string>|number WITH explicit typthint
const observable_or_value = (test: string): Observable<string>|number => Math.random() > 0.5 ? of(test) : 42;
piped<string|number>(observable_or_value).pipe(map(x => x));
// works - x is typeof string|number

// Test 4: … without explicit typehint
piped(observable_or_value).pipe(map(x => x));
// error:
// Argument of type '(test: string) => Observable<string> | number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string) => string | Observable<string>'.
// Type 'number | Observable<string>' is not assignable to type 'string | Observable<string>'.
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string | Observable<string>'.
```

[Full Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwFAEgDGEQCNgDsCmAMgIYz4DOMANKgPJbn5QBuxWANvjShAGY1xBcEMTAChIJgHN8AWVE0AvnF5RMcAORQAHgCtyGgNxITMAJ5h8cAHIQY9RizacAPABUAfHAC8cN3HxtMlwAE3I4AAoHJlYOfBcAV1wAa1wIAHdcDwAfaKc4xJS0zI8AbQBdAEo4AH44AmYmOAAuP2NeJLQYYAhcODBgSxCXeg8I3lxWiNZ2BPxWyig8KWrvLyiGGOd40ezbe03811HKyta82OOsD2R0Xso4EISQEDMANWJZq18NAAl8djsCB%20Cz4AAWeBgAEIjCYUFB8DAElA%20nwIk8Xu9PnNKgA6AaWCKSKAyeRgabY75eW53XAPBHkBLseC%20CYUr6VYwoFDAXgRBlM%20B4SjEXBofB8OAXbaVVDchFIlFwAXM4xyhXI1F8lUwTmoRSnYyKEwAehNfgo8AAjK1cM8sEwkBg6fAZnMAGI%20SJkSgLGBLXArW32pprOAAFgATMYCfgQuyPXjY0TRBFtD4vNpDUgzXB0tBkuEALRwdPAcLmSySu3YR2m81uS1wSPnQ6XeKLZYeJ33eAQNvbL0RH0wP0BoNSgcFTuBrxhtEjvWx%20P9xztpODfAp8npsNZvW5-NQQtwEtliugyUzqQmHMNpsAZlba%202LmvORrDqgcAA6gBJNxfgCbQwHYYA0GAeBKxgCFcBgHsXTgVctjiAB9aBULdb5vUtMdljOScX2nf0u2yT9Qy8eQYNxKBRRCTAImqLwAAZcQAVlqJC%20UXFoI2jJBlzfEjAzIkMoDGZCjnwdCoEwykN0JEQdwzUts0PAti1LOByzgSsJV4OBr1E2soHrC0HnDVpADICPNILBCAEngQJQPAyDdNBWD4OXCJJPbGS5I5fFN23NMVP3YxcyYNQoGaO84AAQRJZ58Dgrj3MsTRh1wwzhJWFTpWI8cvGyeoxI0bTwjSeBiHIchgCkXBBxgYEwGIWjJDIb9JT0zKsLwwNVi8a84BKgrXHfDRcTitxQU0cjv1Gqdxtyjxyp0qq4BquqGqa4Eeo0YbFqI5aism6bZo0ea1squxNtq%20rGriXS9ouw7CJQk6u0moA)

Answer (score 0):

In your test 3

```
Ob = string|number
But it returns an Observable<string> which will never be a number (= Ob)
```

Implenting it like

```js
const observable_or_value = (test: string): Observable<string|number>|number => Math.random() > 0.5 ? of(test) : 42;
piped<string|number>(observable_or_value).pipe(map(x => x));
```

Does fix your problem as `Ob` will effectively be `string|number`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I can only change the function definition. The test functions are fix.